# Webpack 2 import from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

In webpack 2, I'd like to be able to specify subdirectories within specific npm packages to be used when importing them.

Example:

```
// Turn this:
import Module from '@orgscope/module';

// Into this:
import Module from '@orgscope/module/dist';
```

I imagine the [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) section of the config should be able to do what I want but after reading the documentation, I'm still not very clear on how I can achieve the above.

**Update 1**

Adding the package scope

Comment: The one you are describing is a normal use case. What kind of issue have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right on using resolve section of webpack. You can use it something like:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
       'module': 'module/dist'
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question to mention the package scope. I can't get it to work. I don't know if it's because of  the scope or another reason. I am getting a `Cannot find module` error|.